# How to check in configure.ac if build is in termux

Tags: android, configure, autotools, termux

I build my libs for several platforms with autotools. One of the platforms is android in termux environment. 
I'd like to conditionally add android log library with -llog linker option (to debug the app with __android_log_write NDK function).

I currently cannot find a way to determine if the build is for Android because termux returns 'linux' as the target OS.

Is there a way to check if the build environment is 'android' or 'termux' in configure.ac?

Comment: Do you really need to determine whether you're building in termux?  Autoconf is best equipped to check the *capabilities* of the build host.  Wouldn't you want to enable your conditional logging on a hypothetical platform that provided `__android_log_write` but was not termux?  In that case, it's not termux you're looking for, but rather `__android_log_write`, and Autoconf's mechanisms for checking available library functions will suffice..

Comment: I just wanted to add the specific for Android -llog option if build in termux.
Thank you for your suggestion. Seems it is really better to check the lib availability and add it to LDFLAGS.